# logon details in active directory

Tags: active-directory

I'm not familiar with the Active Directory and a User keeps getting locked out of their account for no reason at all. I am trying to find a 'log' to see when they log on/off but can not seem to find one.

Answer (score 2):

You should enable auditing of "[Account Logon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787176%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) [Events](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787567%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)" in "Domain Controller Security Policy".

You should then be able to see logon events in the Event Viewer on the DC.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to lean more toward the user is fat fingering their password.

Here's an article on it though:
[Finding why a user is locked out in Active Directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/65265/finding-why-a-user-is-locked-out-in-active-directory)